# Raspberry pi doesn't recognize HDD NTFS

Tags: hard-drive

I was trying to create a NAS by using my Raspberry Pi B+. I've connected my Samsung 1 TB HDD to USB and then I've used the command `fdisk -l` in order to manually mount the drive.

My Pi didn't recognize it. I've tried to unplug/re-plug it into a different USB port, I've rebooted the Raspberry, I've tried to install `ntfs-3g` (because I used this HDD on Windows so it is formatted with NTFS) but nothing appeared in my terminal.

I've tried different commands such as `fdisk -l`, `lsblk`, `lsusb`, and `dmesg` but my HDD seems to be dead. The fun fact is that the LED on the drive turns on when I plug it into Raspberry and I can notice that the drive is physically vibrating (so the power supply seems to be enough). What can I do? Is it a power problem or the file system? Could anyone please help me? Because the HDD has 500 GB of data and I can't backup everything, format in `ext4` and restore all without the certainty that it will work.

Comment: Most likely a power problem.

Comment: Should I buy a power hub or something like that?

Comment: If you have tried `dmesg` and there's really **nothing** when you connect the drive, then the drive is indeed broken. At the very least, the drive should negotiate the power it will consume, before spinning up. Are you sure you didn't miss something?

Comment: I get :
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# [  102.021235] usb 1-1-port2: over-current change

Comment: Yep, buy a powered hub

Comment: EDIT : I've solved the problem by editing the file /boot/config.txt and adding the line "max_usb_current=1" (i've a B+ and a 2A power supply).

Comment: @luigigigs: Since you figured out the solution to your problem, would you mind posting it as an accepted answer? It will help people who have the same issue later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem by editing the file /boot/config.txt and adding the line "max_usb_current=1" (i've a B+ and a 2A power supply).